# Can Visual Studio Installer add files to user specified directory?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

I am building an installer for an add-on to my company's software. What I need the installer to do, is add a number of files to different directories.
These directories will be subdirectories based on choices the user chooses from a number of dropdownlists.

Can the Visual Studio Installer be set up so that it can do this? I would like to know this is possible before looking into other options such as Wix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really, if I understand your requirement. Visual Studio setups offer only one browse dialog for the Application Folder which is typically the Program Files folder. It sounds like you're looking for multiple locations.

That type of install seems fairly unusual these days because:

1. Most installs know where the files go, the GAC, Common Files, ProgramData etc, because that's where the installed applications expect to find the files.
2. When the other folders are actually the result of a previous install there is often a way to find their locations automatically if that other app leaves paths in the registry, or was a Windows Installer setup, and in both of these cases a search can be used for registry paths or component locations without asking the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you know of any installers which would be able to do what I need? Would you know if Wix can do this?

Comment: All the install tools that I know offer a single browse dialog for the primary application folder. WiX will let create your own dialog in addition, yes.